# Numpy - easier way to change the value of one column of an array only?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to make a 2-D array, with one column staying the same, and the other varying with linspace.

This works, but seems a little bulky:

```
np.hstack((np.tile(45,(21,1)), np.array([np.linspace(55,65,21)]).T))

[[ 45.   55. ]
 [ 45.   55.5]
 [ 45.   56. ]
 [ 45.   56.5]
 [ 45.   57. ]
 [ 45.   57.5]
 [ 45.   58. ]
 [ 45.   58.5]
 [ 45.   59. ]
 [ 45.   59.5]
 [ 45.   60. ]
 [ 45.   60.5]
 [ 45.   61. ]
 [ 45.   61.5]
 [ 45.   62. ]
 [ 45.   62.5]
 [ 45.   63. ]
 [ 45.   63.5]
 [ 45.   64. ]
 [ 45.   64.5]
 [ 45.   65. ]]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could also do it with `a[:, 0] = 45.0`, meaning every first dimension and only the first element in the second dimension. [Check out the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html). Similarly, `a[:, 1] = np.linspace(55, 65, 21)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems cleaner, but else i don't see much advantage:

```
x = np.empty((21, 2))
x[:, 0] = 45
x[:, 1] = np.linspace(55, 65, x.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a great deal better, but I would do

```
>>> a = np.full((21, 2), 45.0)
>>> a[..., 1] = np.linspace(55, 65, a.shape[0])
>>> a
array([[ 45. ,  55. ],
       [ 45. ,  55.5],
       [ 45. ,  56. ],
       [ 45. ,  56.5],
       [ 45. ,  57. ],
       [ 45. ,  57.5],
       [ 45. ,  58. ],
       [ 45. ,  58.5],
       [ 45. ,  59. ],
       [ 45. ,  59.5],
       [ 45. ,  60. ],
       [ 45. ,  60.5],
       [ 45. ,  61. ],
       [ 45. ,  61.5],
       [ 45. ,  62. ],
       [ 45. ,  62.5],
       [ 45. ,  63. ],
       [ 45. ,  63.5],
       [ 45. ,  64. ],
       [ 45. ,  64.5],
       [ 45. ,  65. ]])
>>>
```